# Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange - Key Derivation before Execution

Tags: diffie-hellman, protocol-design, key-exchange

I am dealing with protocol design regarding the Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange (DHKE). The DHKE is performed by the Key Master and some Slave Component. Afterwards, a session key is transmitted using the secure channel provided by the DHKE (i.e. the session key is protected using the shared DH key).

From a logical standpoint, I would suppose that the session key is derived after the DHKE was performed. However, for performance reasons it may be better to derive the session key berforehand (see diagram below).

I am asking myself whether there might be security issues by doing so and whether there are other things that need to be considered w.r.t. order of executed actions.[image]

Edit: The session key is not derived from the shared DH key. Reasoning: The DHKE is performed among the Key Master and multiple Slave Components.

Furthermore, the session key is just used for integrity protection (by calculating a MAC).

Comment: In DHKE, the key derivation can't be before receiving data from the other side.

Comment: Why not, if the key is generated just as a random number of suitable size?

Comment: Oh maybe it is not clear from the description above: I am talking about a session key that is sent encrypted using the shared DH key (i.e. two separate keys)

Comment: @kelalaka Because there are actually multiple slave components. The Key Master performs DHKE with each component separately. Therefore the shared DH keys differs for each pair of (Master, Slave_i), but the session key must be the same for alle components

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks! I edited above. The session key is used for MAC generation and not for encryption

Comment: Now I see what you mean: on side decides the MAC session key. But I do not see why. A DHKE yields a session shared secret that can be used to derive an arbitrary number of session keys using a proper Key Derivation Function (e.g. one for encryption and one for MAC in each direction), with two advantages: the session key transmission is not needed, and a defect in any single RNG won't harm. The only reason I can see to do as in the question is if the DHKE+encryption is a black box and fails to supply integrity protection.

Comment: @fgrieu the reasoning behind that is the following: If we would derive that session key from the DH key, then it would be different for each pair of (Master, Slave_i), but we want just a single session key valid for the master and all slave components

Comment: I see. One drawback is related to use of a single MAC session key: if one of multiple slaves leaks the session key, and integrity depends only on that, then integrity is lost for all slaves. But in many applications this won't be a practical concern. Independently, and more worryingly IMHO, there is the lack of explicit authentication of parties, unless that's hidden in the DHKE box (wich could be authenticated DHKE). Deriving the session key sooner leaves it in memory longer, but if it is shared, that's no big deal.

Comment: Also this only compromises the current session, so should be not much of concern. My main question is actually whether it is fine to derive the session key before establishment of a secure channel. I see no problems with that

Comment: Um, yes, given a secure key generation mechanism, you can create any key as far in advance as you want. Of course, when generated you need to keep it secure. Generally you want to have a session key available for the shortest time possible. The time to generate a symmetric key of 128-256 bits pales in comparison to EC key pair generation, ECDH key agreement and probably the I/O overhead, so if that's the only reason then I would reconsider, even if it doesn't compromise security directly.